# How to use google analytic API to retrieve today data

Tags: datetime, time, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am unable to retrieve the data for **today** visits from google analytics.

If I use this code I got nothing (0):

```
 $request_today = array(
      'metrics' => array('ga:visits'),
      'start_date' => strtotime('today'),
      'end_date' =>  strtotime('tomorrow'), 
 );
$analytic_data_today = @google_analytics_counter_report_data($request_today);
```

If I use this query I get the users of today and yesterday..

```
 $request_today = array(
      'metrics' => array('ga:visits'),
      'start_date' => strtotime('today')-1,
      'end_date' =>  strtotime('tomorrow'), 
 );
$analytic_data_today = @google_analytics_counter_report_data($request_today);
```

Comment: Check out the [API Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/).  You could use this interactively to try and get the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Antonello**, I am afraid what you are trying to do is not possible with "standard" API due to the [data processing delay](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en):

> Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more
>   than 200,000 visits per day to Google Analytics will result in the
>   reports being refreshed only once a day. This can delay updates to
>   reports and metrics for up to two days.

There is [Real-time API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) available as well, only for *Premium* customers though (and only metrics available is number of active visitors).

Answer (score 0):

With this class =  https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface

```
requestReportData($profile_id, array('day'), array('pageviews','visits'),null,null,'today','today');
```